# Application divided by modules?

Tags: android, mobile, google-play

I'm trying to create an application divided by modules, which have a main menu with several OPTIONS to choose in which some are paid and other free.I want to know if it is possible to download these and install modules from the market within the same application.

I can not find any examples on the internet for this, however there are many applications in the market that implement this system.

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

If all the modules are dev by you then ensure that all the modules have at least one entry point(activity). These entry points will have to respond to certain custom intent.

Once the module is downloaded from market, use package manager to find all the activities which responds to your custom intent.

Just play around with [PackageManager APIs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and you will get there.